# One face of the model doesn't behave like the others while scaling/moving

Tags: modeling

I just started on Blender.

Let's use the scale tool for example, when I scale this face (n.1) all the edges around move/adjust along:

[image]
[image]

However, when I move to face n. 2 and try to scale it, see what happens. It keeps the old edges in place and create new ones.
[image]
[image]
What would be the solution for that?

Comment: you obviously have double vertices. that's why you see in 2 a "second" face. You can either select face 2 and press x (face) to delete the 2nd face, then you will see, that there is still another face. And then you can scale as it should. Or you select all vertices in edit by pressing A -> M -> by distance. now you can scale. Hope it helps.

Comment: As @Chris said, there are obviously doubled faces. I guess you started another extrude and cancelled it, but other then cancelling moving, rotating scaling etc. tools like extrusion or duplication do not discard the newly created geometry - it is still there, just in the same place as its source geometry. So I would highly recommend you do his second suggestion, select all and merge by distance - in case there are more areas like this. If you just want to remove this face, after pressing X don't choose delete, but _Dissolve Edges_ or _Vertices_, then there won't be a hole afterwards.